# Let LaTeX choose, if inline or display math is better

Tags: math-mode

This isn't really a ''problem'' for me, but i just wondered if someone knows if there is such an option:

Sometimes I do not care, if my equation is inline or displayed; so I wonder if there is an option that gives LaTeX the control over which math mode has to be chosen depending on how the badness changes.

Comment: Welcome to tex. LaTeX not select math environment. It use, what you tell to it. For example `S` ... `$` for inline math, and `\begin{equation}` ... `\end{equation}` (or any other displayed math environment) for displayed math.

Comment: latex never has access to the paragraph text so for this (and many other reasons) it is essentially impossible to try resetting the paragraph in different ways (the other common example that you can't do is changing the line length at a page break). The price you pay for the memory constraints in 1980.